# How can `printf %q` be reversed in a shell?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, posix, quoting

The command `printf %q` (from GNU coreutils or bash) can be used to quote an array of arguments including whitespaces, newlines and quotes. For example:

```sh
$ main() { printf '%q ' "${@}"; } && main "'a'" '"b"' 'c d' $'e\nf'
\'a\' \"b\" c\ d $'e\nf'
```

Is it possible to reverse this operation, i.e. create an argument array from a string created by `printf %q`

1. In a POSIX shell?
2. In Bash?
3. Using additional tools?

###### Use case for this question

An "argument provider" uses `printf %q "${@}"` to wrap a list of arguments in a single string. The arguments may hold arbitrary content, including but not limited to: quotes, quoted strings with newlines, strings that have been created by `printf %q`. A shell script should be used to unwrap the string into an argument array. Unwrapping should avoid `eval` and unquoted variables. The string may be handed over either as command line argument or by stdout/stdin.

###### Insights

- `xargs` does not handle quoted newlines.
- `zsh` [can do this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677442/501168) for a string stored in variable `args`: `"${(Q@)${(z)args}}"`

Comment: This sounds very [XY](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you actually trying to accomplish? What's the context?

Comment: Thanks. It seems my original question was unclear due to missing context. I added a section explaining my use case and hope that provides enough context now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `declare`:

```sh
quoted=$(main  "'a'" '"b"' 'c d' $'e\nf')
declare -a "myvar=($quoted)"
declare -p myvar
```

outputs

```
declare -a myvar=([0]="'a'" [1]="\"b\"" [2]="c d" [3]=$'e\nf')
```

This can't be used to evaluate commands:

```sh
$ declare -a "myvar=($(main  ls -l sensitive files))"
$ declare -p myvar
declare -a myvar=([0]="ls" [1]="-l" [2]="sensitive" [3]="files")
```

---

One thing to note: if you use `declare` in a function, the variable becomes *local* to that function (unless you use `declare -g` in which case it's global)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, my original question was lacking context. `printf %q` is done in a first script, and the reverse operation should be done in a second script. Does your solution apply to that case? If yes, how can I safely use the `declare` statement in the second shell script, without `eval` or an unquoted variable?

Comment: Answer me this: how does the first script communicate the string to the second script?

Comment: The string is sent to stdout.

Comment: Then, assuming you pipe script1 into script2, script2 would do `quoted=$(cat)` and `declare -a "myvar=($quoted)"` as shown.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm  it works: `quoted=$(cat) && declare -a "args=($quoted)" && printf '>%s< ' "${args[@]}"` prints the 4 values properly with quotes, space and newline.

Answer (score 4):

```
main() { printf '%q ' "${@}"; }
quoted=$(main "'a'" '"b"' 'c d' $'e\nf')
```

> In a POSIX shell?

It's really simple. Use the following to re-set positional arguments:

```
eval "set $quoted"
```

> In Bash?

See answer from Glenn with declare.

> Using additional tools?

Or write a parser of the string that would output "safe" properly quoted string to be sourced with `eval`. Just like GNU `getopt` does. Doing that in POSIX compatible shell will be a challenge, in POSIX C might result in bugs, doing that in python with `shlex` might be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd like to avoid `eval` due to security implications, e.g. `str="; rm -fr /"`

Comment: `e.g. str="; rm -fr /"` But such string does not come from `printf %q`, so it's not part of your question. And e.g. with `printf "%q " "; rm -fr /"` will work fine. So does your string come from `%q` or not? You asked "how `printf %q` can be reversed" not "how double-quoted string from user can be unquoted" - these are separate questions in need of a different approach. If the latter, could be a great idea to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I provided more context by adding my use case to the question. `printf %q` is done in a first script, and the reverse operation should be done in a second script. So, I expect the string to come from `printf %q`, but the second script must be also safe on misuse. I've actually [asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677406/how-to-properly-parse-a-quoted-arg-list-string-in-a-shell-script) the "separate question" you mention.

Comment: Do you know a POSIX solution avoiding `eval`?

Comment: `write a parser of the string that would output "safe" properly quoted string to be sourced`